# PHP rendering image from a class function

Tags: php

I have a simple routing system where a request to the controller class is being sent using the following format:

```
http://localhost/dispatcher.php/some/path/to/needed/file
```

One of the controllers is used to process all requests to get media and asset files such as css, javascript and images.  Class member function that renders these assets like so (css content type is shown):

```
 public function showAsset($request_path) {
     if (file_exists($request_path)) {
         header('Content-type: text/css');
         readfile($file);
}
```

So this works fine with text based files such css and javascript (with text/script header of course), however, when content type

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
```

is specified, the browser shows broken image icon.

Image exists, it shows up fine in the browser if I access it directly bypassing the router.  There is no errors in the server log.  And it works fine if I use this code outside of the application in a test file:

```
<?php
class testClass
{
    public function show()
    {
        $file='test.png';
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        readfile($file);
    }
}

$t=new testClass();
$t->show();
?>
```

Has anyone encountered something like this before?  I'm wondering if the issue has something to do with extra headers or session variables that are getting set somewhere else in the app prior to routing, but I am not sure where to look.

Comment: Did you look at all the headers returned by your browser?

Comment: Nothing unusual,  X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Pragma: no-cache
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Date: Mon, 14 Jul 2014 01:57:40 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 1345
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0

Comment: Compare the content length between the dispatched response versus the direct image file (using `curl -v` from the command line is good for this). There's a chance you have some `echo`'d data either before or after the binary image data.

Comment: Well that seems to be the case, dispatched file is 1 byte longer.  Now the issue is to figure out where is this byte coming from...

Comment: That was it!  Extra line in front of the opening <?php tag in one of the included files.  It was throwing in an extra byte.

Comment: oh damn i was writing this as answer deleted comment x)

Comment: @poctob then mark it as solved.

Comment: This isn't a forum, we don't edit the title to say Solved. Instead, make the answer as accepted by checking the green mark.

Comment: I would, but there was none at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any blank line in your file before header? :v